# Populated values in combobox do not update even on refreshing the combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

My problem is : I have a combobox,which i am populating using the following code.It populates perfectly but i want it to refresh and fetch only the values which have

`deliverystatus ='pending'`

in the database(the combobox is populated for only those details which have a field named delivery status set to 'pending'),after i click the send button,the database is updated with

`deliverystatus=approved`

but the combobox still shows the value i just updated i.e. with

`deliverystatus =approved`

(after send clicked).But i want the value with delivery status =approved' to be removed frm the combobox automatically after i send the details.

```
using (SqlConnection se = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HP-HP;Initial Catalog=MIND;Integrated Security=True"))
{
  try
  {
    SqlDataAdapter d = new SqlDataAdapter("select  UniqueID from deliverydata where delivery_status='Pending' and approvedby=(select name from TEAM where emailid='" + attach.newvalue() + "')", se);
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
    d.Fill(dt);
    comboBox_deliverytypedisp.DataSource = dt.Tables[0]; /// assing the first table of dataset
    comboBox_deliverytypedisp.DisplayMember = "UniqueID";
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // write exception info to log or anything else
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try clearing it first?

```
comboBox_deliverytypedisp.DataSource = null
```

I remember doing something like that with `DataGridView.DataSource`, because it wouldn't refresh other way.

Answer (score 0):

```
 dt.Tables[0].DefaultView.RowFilter = "deliverystatus ='pending'";
 comboBox_deliverytypedisp.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
```

Comment: @user2707945 it's just right in your code, the second line is your code, the first line is my code.

Comment: cannot find column deliverystatus

Comment: @user2707945 as in your question, you talked about `deliverystatus ='pending'`, that's all I know. You should check for the exact name of the column which holds `deliverystatus` and use that name instead of `deliverystatus`.

Comment: yess i am using the exact name..even i am getting the value updated in the database..how to show u an image...cnt link here

Comment: theres no prob at the initial stage...when the form oads fr the frst time it shows what it must,it is only after i click on the button send the prob appears...and the control is not in the formload method when i click on btton send...